# How to Re-Open a Codeswing

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I've just installed the Codeswing extension into VSCode on Windows 11.  When I create a new "swing", it places it here:

> %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\codespaces-contrib.codeswing

It does this even though VSCode has a folder currently open at `c:\repos\experiment`.  Then when I close VSCode, and re-open it to that prior folder `c:\repos\experiment` ...things break.  The Codeswing in the %USERPROFILE% comes back only *partially*: the editor panels re-open, but the web-preview pane originally created by the codeswing is now gone, and there is no option to bring it back.

I presume the codeswing should come back completely, or not at all.  Instead I have this "halfway" behavior.  This "halfway" behavior persists until I completely kill the swing by manually closing each of the remaining windows that the Codeswing originally created.

For VSCode on Windows with Codeswing, my question(s) are:

- How does Codeswing "know" that it has any outstanding swings in my %USERPROFILE%, when I re-open a folder like `c:\repos\experiment`?  It must be storing that information somewhere, but where?
- How do I explicitly open a swing that was stored in the %USERPROFILE% path?  Simply asking the Codeswing to "Open Swing" is apparently not how that should be done...as it doesn't bother to offer the %USERPROFILE% path as an option.
- How can I cause VSCode to "completely" bring back the code swing from my %USERPROFILE% folder, including the web-preview pane, when VSCode re-opens a swing-associated folder (in this case, `c:\repos\experiment`)?

Right now the only way I've found to work with Codeswing, so that it has "stable" behavior, is if I create my swing with the command `New Swing in Directory...`.  This latter command prevents Codeswing from storing anything in my %USERPROFILE% path...and instead causes it to use whatever folder I've opened in VSCode.  When I re-open a swing using this latter, command...it comes back completely, including with the web-preview pane.